# kernel: pass option to driver, when not compiled as module

Tags: linux-kernel, drivers

I had the driver for my sound card compiled as module, i.e.:

```
CONFIG_SND_HDA_INTEL=m
```

and I did pass following options to the module (via `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`):

```
options snd-hda-intel enable=0,1
```

Now I need to have the driver "build in", i.e. not as a module:

```
CONFIG_SND_HDA_INTEL=y
```

How can I pass the options to kernel, when the driver is not a module anymore?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17659798/how-to-pass-a-value-to-builtin-kernel-module-at-boot-time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kernel-parameters.txt), *parameters for modules which are built into the kernel need to be specified on the kernel command line with a module name prefix*.

In this case add `snd_hda_intel.enable=0,1` to your kernel boot line.
You can check the value of the param with:

```
cat /sys/module/snd_hda_intel/parameters/enable
```

Some parameters can be set by writing to this file under `/sys`, but this isn't the case for this particular parameter.